# When I start rendering, all objects are transparent

Tags: rendering

I have just downloaded blender and installed it on my PC, as soon as I open it, if I try to render with the default scene, I get an unusual result. Are there any specific settings to render even such a trivial rendering?
[image]

Comment: Make sure  your graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the setting on the rendering engine in the render properties section of the scene.
By default it is set to "Eevee", by choosing a different one, the render works.

Comment: If the problem only happens in EEVEE, then I still suspect the problem may be GPU/driver related. Do you have an AMD GPU by any chance?

Comment: Yes this is my graphic cads specs:
GPU - AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series
VRAM - 2048 MB - GDDR5 1125 MHz
Graphics Chipset - AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series
SubSystem ID - 7750
SubSystem Vendor ID - 1545
Usable Memory Size - 2048 MB
Memory Type - GDDR5
Memory Clock - 1125 MHz
Core Clock - 800 MHz
Total Memory Bandwidth - 72 GByte/s
Memory Bit Rate - 4.50 Gbps
OpenGL® API Version - 4.6
OpenCL™ API Version - 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the setting on the rendering engine in the render properties section of the scene.
By default it is set to "Eevee", by choosing a different one, the render works.[image][image]